# How to create progress bars in react-native with text inside

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a text to display with variable background color width in the view depending on how much percentage is complete. The problem is the text keeps getting cut off. For example, if I want 20% of the width filled up with gray I wrote code shown below, but the text gets cut off. If I remove numberOfLines={1}, the text doesn't get cut off, but the text continues to the next line. I'm trying to get the text showing in one line

```
        <View style={{margin: 15}}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: `${((100 * 20) / 100).toFixed(1)}%`,
              backgroundColor: 'gray',
              height: 25,
            }}>
            <Text
              numberOfLines={1}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 5,
              }}>
              Item1: 20/100 (20)%
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way I can think of is adjusting the position of your TEXT and make the parent position relative. Something like the code below. I hope it help ;)

```
 <View style={{margin: 15, position: 'relative'}}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: `${((100 * 20) / 100).toFixed(1)}%`,
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
          height: 25,
        }}>
      </View>
      <Text
          numberOfLines={1}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            zIndex: 5,
          }}>
          Item1: 20/100 (20)%
     </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem - I would have never figured it out

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding :)